# How does this function remove all falsy values from an array?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function bouncer( arr ){
return arr.filter( function( value ){
    return value;
});
```

This function removes all falsy values from an array. I don't understand how it works. Does filter automatically *only return* non-falsy values?

Comment: You need to read the documentation of `.filter()`.

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 4):

Because `filter` calls the callback with each value from the array, and builds a new array that includes *only* the values for which `filter` returned a truthy value. So returning the value from the callback only retains truthy values (non-falsy ones), because when the callback returns a falsy value, `filter` leaves that entry out of the array it builds.

For details on how `filter` works, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (readable) or [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter) (markedly less so, but definitive).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as well for filtering truthy values.

It returns a boolean value for every value.

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If the value is omitted or is `0`, `-0`, [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), `false`, [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), `undefined`, or the empty string (`""`), the object has an initial value of `false`. If the DOM object [`document.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all) is passed as a parameter, the new boolean object also has an initial value of `false`. All other values, including any object or the string `"false"`, create an object with an initial value of `true`.

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```